# How to get DRBD nodes out of Connection State StandAlone (and WFConnection)?

Tags: debian, drbd, linux-ha

My Debian 8.9 DRBD 8.4.3 setup somehow has got into a state where the two nodes  cannot connect over the network any more. They should replicate a single resource `r1`, but immediately after `drbdadm down r1; drbadm up r1` on both nodes their `/proc/drbd` describe the situation as follows:

on 1st node (Connection State is either `WFConnection` or `StandAlone`):

```
1: cs:WFConnection ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown C r-----
   ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:912 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:20
```

on 2nd node:

```
1: cs:StandAlone ro:Secondary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown   r-----
   ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:0 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:48
```

The two nodes can ping each other over the IP addresses cited in `/etc/drbd.d/r1.res`, and `netstat` shows that both are listening on the cited port.

How can I (further diagnose and) get out of this situation so that the two nodes can become [Connected](https://docs.linbit.com/doc/users-guide-84/ch-admin/#s-connection-states) and replicate over DRBD again?

BTW, on a higher level of abstraction this problem currently manifests itself by `systemctl start drbd` never exiting, apparently because it gets stuck in `drbdadm wait-connect all` (as suggested by `/lib/systemd/system/drbd.service`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The situation was apparently caused by a case of split-brain.

I had not noticed this because I had only inspected recent journal entries for `drbd.service` (`sudo journalctl -u drbd`), but the problem apparently was reported in other kernel logs and slightly earlier (`sudo journalctl | grep Split-Brain`).

With that, manually solving the split-brain (as described [here](https://www.hastexo.com/resources/hints-and-kinks/solve-drbd-split-brain-4-steps/) or [here](https://docs.linbit.com/doc/users-guide-84/s-resolve-split-brain/)) also resolved the troublesome situation as follows.

On split-brain victim (assuming the DRBD resource is `r1`):

```
drbdadm disconnect r1
drbdadm secondary r1
drbdadm connect --discard-my-data r1
```

On split-brain survivor:

```
drbdadm primary r1
drbdadm connect r1
```

Comment: It's best to include your steps in your answer versus linking to a site that might move later. I imagine you just needed `drbdadm disconnect r1` on both nodes, then `drbdadm connect r1 --discard-my-data` on the victim, and `drbdadm connect r1` on the survivor.

Comment: @MattKereczman Done now.

Comment: Thank you for adding the hint about grepping the journal for split-brain. I was in the same situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern:
On Sick Node(Which is not Current DC, run **pcs status**)

```
drbdadm dump all
drbdadm disconnect resource
drbdadm secondary resource
drbdadm connect resource
```

On Healthy Node (Which is current DC, run **pcs status** )

```
drbdadm dump all
drbdadm disconnect resource
drbdadm primary resource
drbdadm connect resource
```